# Delete link table entry but not referenced table entries

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework database-first model. I have 2 tables that are referenced by a link table. 
For example:

[image]

When I update my edmx file from my database this creates the expected model:

[image]

Now what I want to do is delete an entry from the Product_User table without deleting the referenced entry in either of the related tables (Product or User).

I've tried both of these statements (together and separately) but neither seems to have any effect:

```
    user.Products.Clear();

    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        product.User = null;
    }
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible with the model the way I have it now? And if so what am I doing wrong?

I noticed I can do what I'm trying to do if I add the link table explicitly to the model but I'm trying to avoid that.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your seconde way to go (with a loop) seems more like the correct way.
Instead of `= null` try to use the `.Remove()` function. I guess the remove function only remove the link between the two entity, not the entities related.

See this answer : [Removing many to many entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052438/removing-many-to-many-entity-framework)