# To delete a row from a table of only foreign keys using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a table `User { UserId, Name, Age }` and `License { LicenseId, Name, IsActive }`. Also I have a table `UserLicense { UserId, LicenseId }` which connects both of these and has the record for all the users who hold a license. A user can hold multiple license and those appear as different rows in the `UserLicense` table.

Now I need to remove a particular license from the license table. I do not want to delete it outright, so I mark `IsActive = false`. However I do want to delete rows from the `UserLicense` table for that license Id.

I am using Entity Framework.

If it is a direct table, I would have done something like :

```
var lic = db.Licenses.Where(l => l.Id== licenseId).FirstorDefault();
db.Licenses.Remove(lic);
db.SaveChanges();
```

However since `UserLicense` is a table of foreign keys, Entity Framework does not allow me to access it directly using

```
public void DeleteLicensedUsers(Guid LicenseId)
{
    db.UserLicenses.Where()
}
```

because the model does not contain an independent table for UserLicense as it is only a table of foreign keys.

So how do I delete all rows of `UserLicense` table for a particular `licenseId` using Linq and EF6?

Comment: Add `DbSet<UserLicense> UserLicenses { set;get;}` to your DbContext class and then use it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - Remove object with foreign key, preserving parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858491/entity-framework-remove-object-with-foreign-key-preserving-parent)

Comment: @Shyju no need for that btw, you can use context.Set<UserLicense>() if you hold this type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue and you can solve it this way. I almost tend to avoid tables with just foreign keys and instead add another column to fix this issue.

```
var license = db.Licenses.Where(l => l.ID == LicenseId).FirstOrDefault();
var users = license.Users.ToList();


if (users != null)
{
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
         license.Users.Remove(user);
    }                   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your entity class (I guess `User`), has navigation properties of type `ICollection<Licence>` by removing Licence from this collection you are actually removing items from `UserLicense` table. This is how Entity Framework handles many-to-many relationships in databases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question. So if you mark a license as `isActive = false`, and still want to see that license appear on user's page, then there should still a record in `UserLicense` table associating the two.

That said, I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20055488/2788979) from a similar question will help you.

so essentially:

```
//include licenses in the user entity
var result = ctx.User.Include(x=>x.Licenses).Where(t=>t.Id == _id).FirstOrDefault()
//get the licenses you are looking for, either equal or use .Contains
var licensesOfUser = result.Where(x=>x.Licenses.Where(l=>l.id == _licenseId);
//remove them from entity and save.
result.Licenses.RemoveRange(licenseOfUser);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

[edit: if you have license]

```
//include users in license entities  
var result = ctx.License.Include(x=>x.Users).Where(t=>t.Id == _id).FirstOrDefault()
//get the users you are looking for, either equal or use .Contains
var usersOfLicenses = result.Where(x=>x.Users.Where(l=>l.id == _userId);
//remove them from entity and save.
result.Users.RemoveRange(licenseOfUser);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: When I mark license as isActive = false, I do not want it to appear on User's page. So i indeed want to delete the record in UserLicense table associating the two but do nothing to either the user or the license table.

Comment: oh ok, I understood that wrong, that said the answer linked and the code sample will do exactly what you want .

Comment: .Where(t=>t.Id == _id) this portion does not work as I do not have the user Id but have the license Id.

Comment: then do it the other way, I'll edit my answer [edit]: I've editted so now you can find users associated with a license instead of licenses associated with a your.

Comment: var usersOfLicenses = result.Where(x=>x.Users.Where(l=>l.id == _userId); 

This line has an issue. Firstly results.where does not work and there is no _userId in this context.